# Button naming conventions

Tags: buttons, terminology

I need a common button to upload text and image under a section. Any suggestions please?

Note: On click of the button, a modal window opens and then text and image can be uploaded!!

Comment: It would be good to have some more information around what/why you are uploading? Perhaps a wireframe.  Why would "Upload" not suffice?

Comment: @Thomas Adcock..thanks for the reply...the requirement is that user needs to know what they need to upload...here it is text and image both...usual case, we have "upload" button for image. if am not wrong!!

Comment: So, the user clicks the button, then a popup appears, selects the image, adds text, and then click something else to finish the process, or... ? It is unclear how it looks like/works like as a whole, thus I guess it will be hard to provide good advice.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be my approach on this:

Where "Data" will be in the context of the stuff you are updating.

Example: "Update Flower" , "Update User"

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUcX6Z.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: @Sunilkv You welcome, i just realized you are probably solved it already... the question is from two weeks ago :)

Comment: my mistak for not updating and keeping you wait...thanx for your concern :)

Comment: Now i'm curious, Was your solution similar to what i proposed ? And if so i will appreciate an upvote :)